# Is this a valid way of writing ’ふ’

Tags: handwriting

Have noticed I have a habit of writing ふ　like this when writing hiragana. is it acceptable and legible? (I used my wacom to write this)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you are asking. If I were asked

- What the picture is, I may be confused
- What *hiragana character* it is, I may be able to guess
- What a word containing the picture is, I'll be able to guess by context.

Distorting the shape as you do is not uncommon, as you see in the following page collecting calligraphic examples in old handwriting.

- [「ふ」（U+3075） 日本古典籍くずし字データセット](http://codh.rois.ac.jp/char-shape/unicode/U+3075/)

What is wrong about yours is where the strokes cross. The stroke going to the right should cross the vertical stroke at a lower point.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's sort of legible.  But I would say most likely not acceptable because the way you're hooking it clockwise doesn't really respect the original stroke order, or much resemble the 不 that it originates from.

I personally write it this way in either 1 or 2 strokes (drawn quickly with my finger on my phone), though there are probably some who would not find this acceptable either.

[image]  
[image]